# If a Shared Library being build using some external depenedencies(.so files) would those be required during building the main?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have a doubt with Shared Libraries since I do not have an in-depth understanding of this topic. So my question is that If I built a Shared Library which in turn require some external .so files and If I have a main() method which requires the functionality being implemented on those external .so files so wouldn't be my own Shared library enough to build the class containing the main() method. Since those functionalities would be fulfilled by my own Shared Library.

Maybe I have the wrong idea so would be great if anyone explains. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally you need to list *all* shared libs when linking, also transitive. But with `-Wl,--as-needed` it might be possible.